# How to get single GridFS file using Java driver 3.7+?

Tags: java, mongodb

I need to get single the GridFS file using Java driver 3.7+.

I have two collections with file in a database: `photo.files` and `photo.chunks`.
The `photo.chunks` collection contains the binary file like:

[image]

The `photo.files` collection contains the metadata of the document.
[image]

To find document using simple database I wrote:

```
 Document doc = collection_messages.find(eq("flag", true)).first();
 String messageText = (String) Objects.requireNonNull(doc).get("message");
```

I tried to find file and wrote in same way as with an example above, according to my collections on screens:

```
 MongoDatabase database_photos = mongoClient.getDatabase("database_photos");
 GridFSBucket photos_fs = GridFSBuckets.create(database_photos, 
 "photos");

 ...
 ...

 GridFSFindIterable gridFSFile = photos_fs.find(eq("_id", new ObjectId()));
 String file = Objects.requireNonNull(gridFSFile.first()).getMD5();
```

And like:

```
 GridFSFindIterable gridFSFile = photos_fs.find(eq("_id", new ObjectId()));
 String file = Objects.requireNonNull(gridFSFile.first()).getFilename();
```

But I get an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
    at project.Bot.onUpdateReceived(Bot.java:832)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
```

Also I checked docs of [3.7 driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.7/driver/tutorials/gridfs/), but this example shows how to find several files, but I need single:

```
gridFSBucket.find().forEach(
  new Block<GridFSFile>() {
    public void apply(final GridFSFile gridFSFile) {
        System.out.println(gridFSFile.getFilename());
    }
});
```

Can someone show me an example how to realize it properly?
I mean getting data, e.g. in chunks collection by `Object_id` and md5 field also by `Object_id` in metadata collection.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### To find and use specific files:

```
photos_fs.find(eq("_id", objectId)).forEach(
(Block<GridFSFile>) gridFSFile -> {
// to do something 
});
```

---

or **as alternative**, I can find specific field of the file.
It can be done firstly by creating objectId of the first file, then pass it to [GridFSFindIterable](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.2/com/mongodb/client/gridfs/GridFSFindIterable.html) object to get particular field and value from database and get finally file to convert into String.

```
     MongoDatabase database_photos = 
     mongoClient.getDatabase("database_photos");
     GridFSBucket photos_fs = GridFSBuckets.create(database_photos, 
     "photos");
     ...
     ...
     ObjectId objectId = Objects.requireNonNull(photos_fs.find().first()).getObjectId();
     GridFSFindIterable gridFSFindIterable = photos_fs.find(eq("_id", objectId));
     GridFSFile gridFSFile = Objects.requireNonNull(gridFSFindIterable.first());
     String file =  Objects.requireNonNull(gridFSFile).getMD5();
```

But it checks files from `photo.files` not from `photo.chunks`collection.

[image]

And I'm not sure that this way is code-safe, because of debug info, but it works despite the warning:

```
Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'com.mongodb.client.gridfs.model.GridFSFile' to 'com.mongodb.client.gridfs.GridFSFindIterableImpl'
```

[image]